# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, php

Hello i have a script php and javascript, i want call my function javascript from php, but i have a problem when my string have a new line, when i turn firebug in firefox

this error is 
"**SyntaxError: unterminated string literal**"

This is my code

```
<script>
function myfunction(mydata)
{
   alert(mydata)
}
</script>
<?php 
$data =nl2br("hello \n world");
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="myfunction(\'' . $data . '\')">Click</a>';
?>
```

Help Me, Thank's

Fixed

```
<script>
function myfunction(mydata)
{
   alert(mydata)
}
</script>
<?php 
$data = str_replace("\n", '\n', "hello \n world");
$data = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $data);
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="myfunction(\'' . $data . '\');">Click</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Read the generated source.

Comment: PHP variables are interpreted in double-quotes strings. This is a single-quotes string. Besides, you're calling `onClick="myfunction(Hello <br> world)"`, expect surprises

Comment: what do you mean ??
i don't understand...

Comment: also, you have `data` and `mydata`. you should correct that.

Comment: `'$data'` will yield `$data`. `"$data"` will yield `Hello <br> world`.

Comment: @JeremyThille this alert show >> hello <br> world 
not new line

Comment: Huft... i confused..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an additional treatment to your string to remove line breaks :

```
$data = nl2br("hello \n world");
$data = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $data );
```

Then echo

```
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="myfunction(\'' . $data . '\');"></a>';
```

instead of

```
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="myfunction($data)"></a>';
```

- Add and escape simple quotes between the variable for javascript ton consider it a string
- concat your var to the outputed string because between simple quotes, it will not be interpreted (on the contrary of double quotes).

**Then if you just want to add a line break directly in the alert, you should just do the following :**

```
$data = "hello \\nworld";
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="myfunction(\'' . $data . '\')">Click</a>';
```

If you want to display HTML into an alert box, consider using a popin javascript plugin.

Comment: still error > SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
myfunction('hello <br />

Comment: you can test my code > http://pastebin.com/DCziDDCZ 
this alert show : hello <br /> world

Comment: and what is the problem ?

Comment: That is another problem, and another question. But I edited the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, single quotes will not interpret variables. You need to switch your quote types around, and add quotes around the data variable:

```
echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick=\"myfunction('$data')\"></a>";
```

Comment: you can test my code > pastebin.com/GLAMW8tS this alert show : hello <br /> world